# Can't use PUSH assembler instruction

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to write a function that will reset GPIO0 at my Cortex M3 platform. I'm using Keil compiler.
The goal is to write "1" into address 0x40041014. I wrote a code:

```
static void resetGPIO0()
{
  __asm
  {
    MOV R0, #0x01
    MOV R1, #0x1000
    MOVT R1, #0x4004
    STR R0, [R1, #0x14]
  }
}
```

and it's working but I have a problem that my functions overrides values that were before in R0 and R1. I tried to PUSH them to stack and then POP back, but when I add

```
PUSH {R0, R1}
```

to the beginning of function i get an error:

> 1161: Cannot directly modify the stack pointer SP (r13).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `*(int*)0x40041014 = 1;` ?

Comment: Well the problem is that this code is transformed into:
MOVS R0, #0x01
LDR R1, [pc, #740]
STR R0, [R1, #0x14]
BX LR
and for some really weird reasons I can't use pc there

Comment: R0-R3 are caller-saved by the ARM ABI.

Comment: you will crash the function if you modify the stack pointer, use real assembly.  or as stated above simply write the address (need volatile but dont want to get into a flame war on that, with or without just make sure it works).

Comment: This platform should have C header(s) to manipulate all the hardware on the SoC. Use them appropriately and write your code in C. The ASM you wrote above is not useful for anything (speed and/or size)...

Answer (score 2):

In ARM inline assembly, the registers R13, R14, and R15 [may not be accessed](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0097a/armcc_chdjggff.htm). If you want to do that, you have to write the entire procedure in assembly instead of using inline assembly.

Answer (score 0):

While the `PUSH` instruction doesn't directly access or modify `R13`, it does *indirectly* modify it - which is virtually guaranteed to cause problems for compiler-generated code in the same function.

If that is indeed the reason the compiler is refusing to assemble your - in and of itself perfectly legitimate - `PUSH` instruction (which, of course, you use at your own risk), then the error message it's emitting is poorly worded.

Unfortunately the ARMCC error message documentation sheds no light on this.

(As others have pointed out, you don't need to write any assembler anyway, and certainly not any register-saving code.)